# How do I generate power spectra with different starting times?

Tags: r, wave

I have a sound in .wav format, it has a duration of 3599 seconds, the Seewave library is used to load and process the sound.

```
 sound1 <-readWave()
 n <- (seq(from=16, to=3584,by=32))
 result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(n, function(x)
 meanspec(sound1, from=x,to=(x+32),wl=1024,plot=FALSE,ovlp=50,norm=FALSE)))
```

The above function generates several sections `n` and then a power spectrum for each section.
In the first line, the argument `from=` indicates the time in seconds where the sections start to be made.
The argument `by=`, indicates the duration of each section
result corresponds to a matrix with the X and Y values of the power spectra `(meanspec)`.
With `from= 0` and `8` it generates the spectra, with `from=16` it does not generate the spectra, and it shows me this message:

```
 Error in wave[a:b, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The number for "to" is lower that 3584.
try another number that comes out